# Fetching data from MySQL, problems with diferent query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm fetching some data from a MySQL database in JSON format, but I have a weird problem.

If I write the code:

```
<?php

    //Step1 - Access Database
    ini_set( "display_errors", "1" );
    $db = mysqli_connect('-','-','-','-')
    or exit(mysqli_connect_error());

    //Step2 - Create query and execute it

    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `Tiendas`";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or exit(mysqli_error($db));

    //Step 3 - Configure results

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    //Step 4 - Close connection and send results
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    mysqli_close($db);
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

It works well, but if I write:

```
<?php

    //Step1 - Access Database
    ini_set( "display_errors", "1" );
    $db = mysqli_connect('-','-','-','-')
    or exit(mysqli_connect_error());

    //Step2 - Create query and execute it

    $query = "SELECT `Tienda` FROM `Tiendas`";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or exit(mysqli_error($db));

    //Step 3 - Configure results

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    //Step 4 - Close connection and send results
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    mysqli_close($db);
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

It doesn't show anything. Neither an error code...

The Table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Tiendas` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Usuario` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Tienda` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=217
;
```

It doesn't work if I include in the SELECT statement the "Tienda" or the "Usuario" row. If I only include the "id" row it works well...

Comment: What does the var_dump give you?

Comment: what does the `cdm` part stand for in your FROM `cdm`.`Tiendas`? I don't know what that syntax means in the FROM of a query but it seems to me like you just need FROM `Tiendas` by the description of your table. e.g. "SELECT `Tienda` FROM `Tiendas`"

Comment: cdm is the database. It can be removed.

Comment: var_dump shows the result correctly. But it shows results like "SAT�LITE". Could it be an encoding problem?

Comment: ah, okay, I was under the impression you chose a database in the connect and had to stick with it, the more you know

Comment: I removed the `cdm`in the question so is clear, thanks

Comment: Did you trying this sql in your DB?

Comment: if it's the charset you could try `mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8")` and see if that resolves the SAT�LITE thingie at least

Comment: The SQL works well in my DB. The var_dump return the correct result as I said before. Something like that: [137]=> array(1) { ["Tienda"]=> string(17) "SERCABLE TRAVES�A" }

Comment: I solved as I commented in the answer, but the results like {"Tienda":"M\u00d3VILES"} instead of {"Tienda":"MÓVILES"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it changing the encoding...

```
<?php

    //Step1 - Access Database
    ini_set( "display_errors", "1" );
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','fgallegof','qU5v6f5$','cdm')
    or exit(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");

    //Step2 - Create query and execute it

    $query = "SELECT `Tienda` FROM `Tiendas`";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or exit(mysqli_error($db));

    //Step 3 - Configure results

    $data = array();
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    //var_dump($data);

    //Step 4 - Close connection and send results
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    mysqli_close($db);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I need to add the `mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");` and modify the last line relative to the encoding of JSON